# Select the next row after nth duplicate rows

Tags: c#, linq

I am making a probability game in order to prove that fliping coins have no memory. In other words if I have flipped 2 heads in a row the next flip has the same probability of being tailes or heads. I am generating random numbers. A 1 represents a tail and a 0 represent  a head for example.  I am recording the results in a List. Therefore that list contains 1's and 0's. How could perform a select to just get the rows after 3 consecutive heads or tails for example. In other words if I have the list:

0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1

I want to get 1,1

Because the there are three 0 that repeat and the next number is a 1. And the next 1 is because the number after 3 consecutive 1's is a 1

---

I know I can perform that select iterating through a loop and having a counter inside that every time there are duplicates the counter increments but I was wondering if it is posible to do that with a linq query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is similar to this other SO question  [Can I use LINQ to retrieve only "on change" values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194761/can-i-use-linq-to-retrieve-only-on-change-values)

The answer by Thomas Petricek suggests creating on override on the GroupBy extension method.  That technique should provide you with what you want, plus it creates the ability to do aggregate functions on your key breaks.

Thomas must have really obsessed over this question because he wrote an in depth article on creating a custom GroupBy for grouping adjacent key values.  Here is that article:  http://tomasp.net/blog/custom-linq-grouping.aspx

If you use the technique suggested in this article then you have a nice clean way to pull the duplicated rows.

```
int[] coinTossResults = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1};
var tails = (from x in coinTossResults.WithAdjacentGrouping()
             group x by x into g
             where g.Count() > 1 && g.Key == 1
             select g);
```

The WithAdjacentGrouping creates the IAdjacentGroup type which has the override for GroupBy.

Comment: +1.  Superior to my answer because it solves this in a general-purpose way, and doesn't involve any weird state hacks (closure state, or linq with side-effects).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how it can be done. At the very least the solution is not obvious, if you do this for instance,

```
    int[] integers = new int[] {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1};

    var values = integers.Select(x => 
        {
            return x == 1;
        });
```

You get to the point where you are writing the select predicate, and you realise that you are only dealing with one of the items in the list at a time. There doesn't seem to be a way to determine what the previous three items are. If that can be solved then it might be possible.

You then end up with something like this,

```
int[] integers = new int[] {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1};

List<int> results = new List<int>();

for (int pos = 0; pos < integers.Length; pos++)
{
    if (pos > 2)
    {
        if (integers[pos - 1] == integers[pos - 2] && integers[pos - 2] == integers[pos - 3])
        {
            results.Add(integers[pos]);
        }
    }
}
```

Which is not necessarily what you are after, but something to think about.

Comment: You should just set `int pos = 3` to start with, then you don't have to have an `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Any sort of run count algorithm requires multiple state variables:

- current value
- previous value
- current run count

The closest thing to getting you there is `Enumerable.Aggregate`, because it gives you both the current value, and some custom per-item value that you choose to output.  In our case, it will probably be the previous value.

With a simple `int[]`, you'd have to have some extra state for the `current run count`.  This would have to be placed outside your Linq query statements.  While it would work, it wouldn't be terribly different from using a for-loop.

If you instead modify your enumeration to be a custom structure, you can modify that structure to also contain the run count, and you can do a (somewhat) more linq-friendly operation:

```
class Program
{
    class CoinToss
    {
        public int Value;
        public int RunCount;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] values = new int[]
        {
            0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
        };

        var coinTosses = values
            .Select(v => new CoinToss() { Value = v, RunCount = 1 })
            .ToList();

        coinTosses.Aggregate(
            (previous, current) =>
            {
                current.RunCount = current.Value == previous.Value
                    ? previous.RunCount + 1
                    : 1;
                return current;
            });

        foreach (var coinToss in coinTosses)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}, Run Count: {1}",
                coinToss.Value,
                coinToss.RunCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it is a little weird for Linq operations to have side-effects, so it all depends on how pure you want to be...

After this, you can simply select:

```
coinTosses.Where(coinToss => coinToss.RunCount >= 3);
```

Unfortunately you can't chain the `Aggregate` function, so you'll have to build the whole list for this to work.  If this is a problem, you should simply use a loop and `yield return` instead, since your requirements are a little beyond a "query".